# List records that have multiple collaborators

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to list all the records that have more than one different collaborators ("added_by") as per table below:

[image: Table: report]

The result expected are **report_id** having values **103**, **104**.

**report_id** having value **102** has been excluded because the entries have been added twice by the same user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to translate your requirements is to aggregate your table by report and retain those reports having more than one distinct contributor.

```
SELECT 
    report_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    report_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT added_by) > 1
```